# How to 3D view an OBJ or STL object given its URL?

Tags: 3d-models, stl, obj

I have OBJ and STL files generated by reality capture software and stored on a website.

I'd like to send our users web links that will take them to a 3D object web viewer loaded with the corresponding object.

I can't seem to find a simple online viewer that can do this given a URL.   What do you suggest?

Comment: A utility like that likely does not exist, As most sites would rather people hotlink directly to their services. https://viewstl.com provides a 'load from URL' function, but does not appear to have any way to send a link that would automatically open a model.

Comment: with webgl, in might even entirely be doable as all client side.  just no big open source thing for it yet...